# How many 2-Sylow subgroups does the group $D_n$ have?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, dihedral-groups

How many 2-Sylow subgroups does the group $D_n$ have?

We're trying to solve it by considering the case n is odd and n is even, but stucked in the case that n is odd.

Thank you very much!

```
Problem solved, thanks to Mark Bennett!
```

Comment: If $n$ is odd, what is the order of the 2-Sylow Subgroups?

Comment: if n is odd, the order of 2-Sylow subgroups will be 2.

Comment: And a group of order 2 is cyclic? And generated by an element of order 2? And if you understand the dihedral groups geometrically, what are the elements of order 2?

Comment: @ShuHu You can write the answer here if you want, so that this question will be removed from the unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

|$D_n$| = 2n
if n is an odd, the largest power of 2 that div |$D_n$| is 2, and we can find a 2-Sylow subgroup K={1, E}. By proving $N_{D_n}(K)=2$, we get $n_2$($D_n$)=2n/2=n.

if n is an even, we can construct a 2-Sylow subgroup K with size $2^m$(the largest power of 2 that div |$D_n$|). Then by proving K is a normal subgroup, we get it's the unique 2-Sylow subgroup and $n_2$($D_n$)=1.